# name error after basic intput in python

Tags: python, macos, nameerror

my code in Python

```
name = input('Name: ')
Name: Jeffrey
```

and my error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Jeffrey' is not defined
```

I have no idea what is going on here. I am using python 3.4.5 on a mac uploaded through pyenv install 3.4.5

Comment: Seems like you're using Python 2 still. Run `print(sys.version)` to see which python version is actually being used, you have to import `sys` first as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're still using Python2.x.

Because in Python3.x `input` will return a string,and you won't got this error.

If you're using Python2.x `input` function evaluates your input and tries to run the input as a Python expression.So if your input is a string ,you will got :

```
NameError: name 'xx' is not defined
```

Add this to your code and get your Python version.And you will see what's wrong with your code.

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
name=raw_input('name : ')
```